# Why does ls wrap some filenames in single quotes?

Tags: linux, unix, ls, coreutils

I've noticed that when I do `ls` in a terminal, some filenames are wrapped in single quotes and some aren't.

I don't like the way this looks as I prefer my terminal outputs to be nice and uniform. What causes this functionality, and is it possible to safely disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Why `ls` wraps some filenames in single quotes

`ls` wraps single quotes around filenames with spaces in them, for the purpose of allowing the filenames to be safely copied, used in a script or piped through another command.

[image]

This was a [highly unpopular](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-is-ls-suddenly-wrapping-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes) feature [introduced to version 8.25](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2016-02/msg00000.html) of the GNU `coreutils` package as recently as 2016, by a consensus of just three developers.

Arguments cited by critics of the change include that it makes the output of `ls` look considerably more unsightly, [unnecessarily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) diverges from nearly half a century of Unix tradition, and due to the way it was implemented (opt-out instead of opt-in) breaks compatibility with long-standing existing scripts and utilities.

Because the feature was introduced to the `coreutils` package - which virtually every Linux distribution depends on and which `ls` is a part of - the change affects every Linux or Linux-like system imaginable, from Arch Linux to Cygwin.

In the case of Debian and Debian-derived distros like Ubuntu, the change was at some point reverted after considerable protest, before being [once again reinstated in October 2017](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=877582).

As [this answer makes clear](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/262162/216754), the best way to register your disappointment at this change would be to contact the `coreutils` developers directly via a bug report and (politely) make the argument that they've made a huge mistake. As per the open source ethos, a critical mass of users respectfully but adamantly insisting that the way `ls` used to behave be properly reinstated should in theory be enough to convince the `coreutils` developers to listen to the Linux community.

---

## Restoring `ls`' pre-*version 8.25* behaviour

In the more short-term, pragmatic sense, there are several ways you can restore `ls`' pre-*version 8.25* behaviour of leaving all output  intact. Below are three methods to doing so for the `bash` shell.

#### Use the *QUOTING_STYLE* environment variable

Find your `~/.bashrc` file in your HOME folder (`/home/yourusername`), and add the following line to it:

```
export QUOTING_STYLE=literal
```

Save the file, and the change should apply immediately to all new `bash` terminals that you open.

You can also run `source ~/.bashrc` to have the changes be pushed to any terminal windows that were open at the time of making the change.

#### Create an alias to `ls -N`

If you prefer aliases to environment variables, you can also create an alias in `.bashrc` that uses 8.25's new `-N` switch. From `ls --help`:

> *-N*, *--literal* print entry names without quoting

To do this, add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file and save it:

```
alias ls="ls -N"
```

Run `source ~/.bashrc` to have the new change be pushed to all open terminals.

#### For the current run only: use the `-N` command-line switch

If you prefer `coreutils`' new default behaviour but want to bypass it temporarily, you can also use the `-N` switch directly in a command:

```
ls -N
```

Comment: It was not my intention to be passive-aggressive, but since you perceived my comment as such, maybe I was. My apologies then, comment deleted. I genuinely upvoted the answer and the question, this means I think they are useful here on SU.

Comment: I thought I'd find the default behaviour useful and indeed it is for copy and pasting, but I've realized that that's a lot less important than just trying to read the output of `ls` without going insane. My mp3 files have a lot of apostrophes in them.

Comment: I understand the anger this change caused, but as far as I know it would not affect scripts or utilities as it only occurs in interactive shells.